# How to return value from function run by multiprocessing process

Tags: python, multiprocess

The variable `time_completed` gets `None` while the goal is to get time at which the `process` function was completed. How to make sure the time is returned back to the `parent`?

```
import time, multiprocessing

def process():
    num = int()
    while True:
        print '...sleeping %s' % num
        time.sleep(1)
        num += 1
        if num > 10:
            break
    return time.time() 


class Child(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()

    def process(self):
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=process)
        proc.start()

class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Parent, self).__init__()
        child = Child()
        time_completed = child.process()
        print 'time_completed: %s' % time_completed



obj = Parent()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Pipe`, or a shared memory `Value` (or similarly an `Array`), to communicate between processes. Here's an example of using a `Pipe`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(p):
    msg = 'Hello from child!'
    print("sending {!r} to parent".format(msg))
    p.send(msg)
    v = p.recv()
    print("got {!r} from parent".format(v))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p_conn, c_conn = mp.Pipe()
    p = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(c_conn,))
    p.start()
    msg = 'Hello from parent!'
    print("got {!r} from child".format(p_conn.recv()))
    print("sending {!r} to child".format(msg))
    p_conn.send(msg)
    p.join()
```

Or, you could use a `Pool`, which works in the most general case of needing `N` embarrassingly parallel workers, each with a return value.  (Note, I'm using `multiprocess` here, which is a bit more flexible than `multiprocessing` -- e.g. it works better in the interpreter):

```
>>> import multiprocess as mp
>>> import time
>>> def process(n):
...     num = int()
...     while True:
...         print '...sleeping %s' % num
...         time.sleep(1)
...         num += 1
...         if num > 10:
...             break
...     return time.time() 
... 
>>> mp.Pool(2).map(process, [None]*2)
...sleeping 0
...sleeping 0
...sleeping 1
...sleeping 1
...sleeping 2
...sleeping 2
...sleeping 3
...sleeping 3
...sleeping 4
...sleeping 4
...sleeping 5
...sleeping 5
...sleeping 6
...sleeping 6
...sleeping 7
...sleeping 7
...sleeping 8
...sleeping 8
...sleeping 9
...sleeping 9
...sleeping 10
...sleeping 10
[1540486371.700522, 1540486371.700522]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to wait for your processes.
For example by calling join.

Second, process() should store a value in Child that can be access afterwards and returned.

Comment: Good idea! Unfortunately the function `process` does not get a `child` object, in order for it, to be able to store a value. Is there a way to update a `child` object from a `process` without sending a `child` object to the `process` function in a first place?

Comment: That's kind of the point. First of all: don't name everything process, that could be make it easier for you to understand your code. Second: pass arguments or use objects when you need to store data.